# i was trying to run this code and keeps giving me this erorr result.push(3) AttributeError: 'Stack' object has no attribute 'push'

Tags: python, algorithm

```
class Stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.items= []

def is_empty(self):
            return not self.items

def push(self, item):
            self.items.append(item)

def pop(self):
    return self.items.pop()

def peek(self):
    return self.items [-1]

def size(self):
     return len(self.items)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.items)

if __name__=="__main__":
    result = Stack()
    print(result)
    result.push(3)
```

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. All the function definitions need to be indented so they're inside the class.

Comment: Is that how your code is indented?

Comment: The importance of indentation should be one of the first things you learn about Python.

Answer (score 1):

Python is heavily dependent upon indentation, so getting it right is crucial. As you have it now, `Stack` only has one method, `__init__`, as all of your other functions are defined globally. This can be fixed by having the rest of the intended methods being indented as equally as `__init__`, changing their scope.

Here is a working indentation:

```
class Stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.items= []

    def is_empty(self):
        return not self.items

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def peek(self):
        return self.items [-1]

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.items)

if __name__=="__main__":
    result = Stack()
    print(result)
    result.push(3)
```